# By creating a new user, does it have read and write permission to its own home directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, users, home

I am totally new to the Linux world. If I create a new user, does it have read and write permission to its own home directory by default?

Logically, it should, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new user means just adding a new entry to a relevant "database". In a most basic (e.g. home) setup the "database" is just text in `/etc/passwd` file. See `man 5 passwd`.

One can add an entry manually, a relatively safe way is `sudo vipw`. "Relatively", because you really shouldn't do this manually, especially if you're "totally new in Linux world". Still it's totally possible.

Simply adding an entry to the file does not create a home directory, does not alter existing directories, does not change their mode (permissions) or ownership. It's possible to specify a nonexistent directory. In my Debian there's `nobody` user with `/noexistent` home directory. This path does not exist. Still I (having root privileges) can start a process as `nobody`, the user is valid.

"Real" users, who want to log in interactively, almost always need and want respective home directories with read and write permissions. Your intuition is quite right: usually they should have them.

Basically it's the admin's job to create a setup that works for OS and its users.

Here come programs that automate the task of creating users, at least to some degree. E.g. in Debian there is `adduser`. It can create a new user, create a home directory for the user, copy skeletal files to the directory, set sane ownership and permissions up. Desktop environment (if any) may provide a way to add users via GUI (graphical user interface, i.e. not in a text console) and also set additional things up. If available, such specialized program or functionality is usually the right way to add a new user. In general there may be ways to configure the program to skip some steps, but the default configuration should not surprise you much.

To summarize:

> If I create a new user, does it have read and write permission to its own home directory by default?

- In general, by default – no, not necessarily, maybe by chance (e.g. if you specify a directory readable and writable for everyone) or if *you* (the admin) take care of this.
- In a common distro, by using a user-friendly tool designed to manage users and to create home directories anew – yes (unless explicitly (miss)configured otherwise).

Comment: thanks a lot for your informations! could you write an example, which I can create a user and has read and write permission to its own home directory, please?

Comment: @NaseerAkbari What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I use, Fedora 32 and Ubuntu!

Comment: @NaseerAkbari I don't know Fedora. Ubuntu is based on Debian, there is `adduser` in it. See `man 8 adduser` and where it says "`adduser` will create a home directory …". Both distros should support `useradd` which does not create a home directory. `adduser` is deliberately designed to do more than `useradd`. An example command is `sudo adduser joe`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your support!